# Is there a way to hide folders from the file view in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C++ and Visual Studio, and I can't seem to find a way to hide folders from the file view.

I am talking specifically about the file view in Visual Studio (I'm not trying to hide filters) and I am wondering if you can hide folders like the generated x64 or x86 folders when compiling C++ code from the view, so that you are only looking at the project files, rather than the generated folders. I have tried searching for results, but couldn't find anything useful.

Below is an image of the file view:

[image: this is what the file view looks like]

Comment: I searched the file view but couldn't find the relevant information. What is file view? If you only open the **.sln** file, you will not see generated folders.

Comment: They are created when running the code in debug or release mode (you may have to reload it to see it after running the program). Admittedly, it's not a big deal, but it would be good to know if there is a way to hide files that are just making the project untidy.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT sorry, I added an edit with a link to an image of what the file view looks like (just press the symbol with the three documents in it to change from the regular view to the file view).